# adjusting UIImage width in cell

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a `UIImageView` inside a `UITableViewCell` and depending on the type of iPhone thats being used, I want to adjust the **width** of the `UIImageView`. The problem is when I try to set the **width** in `awakeFromNib`, the **width** of the `ImageView` remains same i.e. in the `NIB` file. Heres my code.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height
    if screenHeight == 568 {
        ProductImage.frame.size.width = 200
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }else if screenHeight == 667 {
        ProductImage.frame.size.width = 50
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }else if screenHeight == 736 {
        ProductImage.frame.size.width = 100
        self.layoutIfNeeded()

    }


}
```

Comment: Have you looked into using auto layout?

Comment: yes and its not doing what i need. how can i make the code above work

Comment: what you wanted to do , please explain ,, if  you want to do usign Code , shift code from `awkeNib` to `drawRect`

Comment: nope that didn't work, I want to adjust the width of an image view in a tableview cell depending on what the screen size is

Comment: Frames are not set in awakeFromNib... you want to look into `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview

Comment: you can use size class for it, and set custom size for imageView from IB itself.

Comment: deepak could you show me how to do that in an edit. Im a little confused on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar problems. Have you tried implementing viewDidLayoutSubviews() ? I think here you can adjust the size. Just remember to call super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()